# Convert a multirow dataframe into a single row dataframe with paired columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   Mean_58   58   Mean_59   59   ...   Mean_350   350
0  7         2    4         3          6          5 
1  8         1    2         5          8          3
2  3         1    9         7          8          9
```

I'd like to create a one row dataframe, called row_dataframe, that has the following column headers and order:

```
   Mean_58_1   58_1   Mean_58_2   58_2   Mean_58_3   58_3 ... Mean_350_3 350_3
0  7           2      8           1      3           1        8          9
```

I've seen similar answers that use `unstack` and `sort_index`, but how could you pair the columns like I did in row_dataframe? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try with df.reset_index().melt('index')

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can actually use melt. Let's take this df for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(4,5),columns=["a","b","c","d","e"])
#Output
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2   10  11  12  13  14
3   15  16  17  18  19
```

Now you turn it around a little bit and get what you want:

```
intermediate = pd.melt(df,id_vars=["index"],value_vars=df.columns.difference(["index"]))
cols = intermediate["variable"].astype("str") + "_" + intermediate["index"].astype("str")
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols.values,data=intermediate["value"].values.reshape(1,20))

#Output
a_0     a_1     a_2     a_3     b_0     b_1     b_2     b_3     c_0     c_1     c_2     c_3     d_0     d_1     d_2     d_3     e_0     e_1     e_2     e_3
0       5       10      15      1       6       11      16      2      7       12        17     3       8       13      18      4       9       14      19
```

but I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do it.